# Organic Chemistry..What is the order of importance when naming a hydrocarbon?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, hydrocarbons

What is the order of importance when naming a hydrocarbon?
How do you know what becomes the suffix, and what becomes the prefix between the functional groups?

Comment: are you sure you are talking about hydrocarbons, when talking about functional groups? by the way, welcome to Chem.SE

Comment: maybe related?: [Functional group naming order?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/functional-group-naming-order)

Answer (score 1):

It's rather long story. Here is a relevant part of almost official transcript of IUPAC Organic chemistry recommendations: [Guide to Name Construction, R-4.1 General Principles](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_317.htm)